# Update Bar Chart in d3

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I have a question about updating a bar chart in d3.js. I've played around with the transition function but can't seem to get it working.

Here is the code for the basic bar chart:

```
 <script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.tsv("data/data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  var barWidth = width / data.length;

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("width", barWidth - 1);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency) + 3; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.frequency; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency; 
  return d;
}
```

And so far, I have this for the update function:

```
 function updateBarData(){

           var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])

        d3.tsv("data/data3.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })])  
      })

           var barupdate = chart.selectAll("")
           .data(data);

        barupdate.enter()
       .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; })

  barupdate.append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("width", barWidth - 1);

  barupdate.append("text")
      .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency) + 3; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.frequency; });


           barupdate.transition()
         .duration(1000)
       .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; })

  barupdate.append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("width", barWidth - 1);

  barupdate.append("text")
      .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency) + 3; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.frequency; });





         barupdate.exit().transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .remove();




               }
```

I've been starting at this all day, so may be missing something blindingly obvious, but would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Update 1:

```
function updateBarData(){

    d3.tsv("data/data3.tsv", type, function(error, data) {

  })

   var updatechart = g.selectAll("body")
   .data(data)

   updatechart.enter().insert("rect")
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
  .attr("width", barWidth - 1)

   updatechart.transition()
   .duration(1000)
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })

   updatechart.exit()
   .remove();




           }
```

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html)?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I've half based mine off, but his bar charts are less complex than mine plus he is using streaming data, rather than two JSON files loaded in from an external source..

Comment: So would something as simple as update 1 work?

Comment: In principle yes. D3 makes this kind of thing quite easy.